# .Net (2.0) Asynchronous Thread vs. UI Thread Performance

Tags: .net, multithreading, user-interface, asynchronous, recursion

I am looking for an explanation into why when I run code that does some heavy recursive processing on the UI thread the code executes in around 90 secounds. Yet when I run the same code on an Asynchronous thread (not the UI thread) the code executes almost instantly? Any explanation would be appreciated.

TY,
Josh

Comment: Can you post some code around the two scenarios ? Are other factors equal in both cases ? With the given info , I cannot think of a particular reason it should be this way.

Comment: Posting code isn't an option.The factors "seem" to be equal in both cases. I posted the question becuase "With the given info , I cannot think of a particular reason it should be this way". So you are reiterating my question.TY.

Comment: What makes you believe that the async code is executed instantly? Are you sure it returns the correct values? What method are you using to signal completion?

Comment: After the processing is complete I load a TreeView and can visually confirm that I get the same result. I also have some debug statements that confirm the results. I am using a ManualResetEvent (.Set()) to signal the UI that my Async thread has finished processing. Thank you for your response.

Comment: Why is posting the code not on option?  Is the code updating any public properties?

Comment: Blam - Becuase I can lose my job if i do. :)

Answer (score 1):

There could be a handful of answers.  If you are updating databound data fields then the UI may be doing a lot of work to render the updated data.  This could cause your processing to slow down many orders of magnitude.

Also, if you are on a memory constrained machine and you have a large UI, then you may be hitting memory limitations while you have th UI open.  Perhaps you are thrashing around in the page file.

Also, it may be possible depending on your type of UI that there are stack size or other limitations which you are running into which are not present when the code is run on a different thread.

Is your UI catching any events that could be thrown from data altered by your recursive processing?

Comment: Thank you for your response. I considered the possibly of "updating databound data fields" slowing the code down, so I isolated the recursive logic for any UI databinding.

Comment: As far as memmory is concerned, I don't believe this is the issue as the 12,000 ojects the code is recursively searching are relatively light (and the machine I am running the code has 16GB RAM with most of it free).For your third suggestion, while I am not catching or explictly throwing any events it is possible that the system is generating UI events. TY for your suggestions.